# requests_html library error=Cannot use HTMLSession within an existing event loop. Use AsyncHTMLSession instead

Tags: python, request, python-requests-html

I was trying to use the library requests_html in my jupyter notebook when I step with the error of:

> Cannot use HTMLSession within an existing event loop. Use AsyncHTMLSession instead.

I search for solutions and found this one:

```
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```

**But when I apply it to mi code:**

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import nest_asyncio

nest_asyncio.apply()

session = HTMLSession()

r = session.get('http://python-requests.org')

r.html.render()

print(r.html.search('Python 2 will retire in only {months} months!')) # None
```

The error keeps going.
Do you know any solution for this problem?

Comment: Can you try running it as just a python file?

Comment: Is a nice quick fix , thank you!

Comment: For what it's worth, some people find Jupyter useful for rapid prototyping. It will be immensely useful if requests-html supports jupyter out of the box. If it can't -at all-, it's nice to hear some explanation why.